# How do I specify a package installation (for Yarn) within a CircleCI docker image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, circleci

I am using CircleCI to test a Rails app. I need to run have my images use a later version of Yarn (1.19 currently) than is available off the image we are using for our CI tests (`circleci/ruby:2.6-node-browsers`).

What is the configuration step/entry in `config.yml` to do this? I assume I have to run something in the build step that upgrades the Yarn version (which in the image is currently 1.17.) But I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: have you read https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/yarn/

Comment: Yes, and I couldn't understand what it was instructing me to do - I guess I am supposed to add the `curl` command, but I can't figure out where within the `circleci/config.yml` that line should go.

Comment: I did realize I could add the install instruction as an entry in the `steps` section, but the issue is that we also have a cache that's dependent on the checksum of the yarn.lock file. This means that the older version of 1.17 in the cache is still used - if I can figure out how to make the cache dependent on the yarn version, I think I will have solved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with [the Circle docs on Yarn](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/yarn/), I tried installing Yarn through that `curl` command they have in their example (as of Oct '19), which goes:

```
run:
  name: install Yarn
  command: curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
```

This did *not* work - `yarn -v` still returned 1.17.

I subsequently heard back from CircleCI support, and changed this to:

```
      - run: |
          curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
          echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ rc main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
          sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
          sudo rm /usr/local/bin/yarn && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn
```

and that worked. I am going to guess it's because the use of `sudo` sets the global path soft links correctly, and the local install did not. I could possibly have gotten here by resetting the `PATH` variable but I am pasting this here, because using the `apt` route seems the "better" solution to me.